# Bayes estimate for loss function $\ell(t,\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}(t-\alpha^2)^2$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, parameter-estimation, bayes-theorem

> I am given the following info for $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$:
> $$X\sim f(X|\alpha)=\alpha X^{-(\alpha+1)}I(X>1).$$
> Propose a convenient family of priors and find the Bayes estimate for the loss function $\ell(t,\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}(t-\alpha^2)^2$.

The joint distribution is of the form
$$f(\underline{X}|\alpha)=\alpha^n\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i^{-(\alpha+1)}I(X_i>1)=\alpha^n e^{-(\alpha+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(X_i)}I(X_{(1)}>1).$$
Then, $\text{Gamma}(a,b)$ seem like good priors with a posterior $\text{Gamma}(a+n,\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\log(X_i)+b)$.

To find the posterior:

$$P(\alpha|X)\propto P(X|\alpha)P(\alpha)\propto\alpha^n e^{-\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(X_i)}e^{-b\alpha}\alpha^{a-1}$$.

Adding the like terms gives us the posterior.
To find the Bayes estimate we minimize with respect to $t$, we consider the following Bayes risk function
$$\int \ell(t,\alpha)f(\alpha|\underline{X})d\alpha=\int \frac{1}{\alpha^2}(t-\alpha^2)^2f(\alpha|\underline{X})d\alpha.$$
Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{1}{\alpha^2}(t-\alpha^2)^2=\frac{2t}{\alpha^2}-2$ and
$\int (\frac{2t}{\alpha^2}-2)f(\alpha|\underline{X})d\alpha<\infty$, we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int \ell(t,\alpha)f(\alpha|\underline{X})d\alpha=2\int \left(\frac{t}{\alpha^2}-1\right)f(\alpha|\underline{X})d\alpha
= 2tE\bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\bigg|\underline{X}\bigg]-2.$$
Setting this equal to $0$ implies the Bayes estimate is $$\hat{t}=\frac{1}{E\bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\bigg|\underline{X}\bigg]}.$$
Define $R=\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\log(X_i)$.
Then
\begin{align}
E\bigg[\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\bigg|\underline{X}\bigg]
& =\int \alpha^{-2}\frac{(R+b)^{n+a}}{\Gamma(n+a)}\alpha^{n+a-1}e^{-\alpha(R+b)}d\alpha \\
& = \frac{(R+b)^{n+a}}{\Gamma(n+a)}\frac{\Gamma(n+a-2)}{(R+b)^{n+a-2}}\int \frac{(R+b)^{n+a-2}}{\Gamma(n+a-2)}\alpha^{n+a-2-1}e^{-\alpha(R+b)}d\alpha \\
& =\frac{(R+b)^{n+a}}{\Gamma(n+a)}\frac{\Gamma(n+a-2)}{(R+b)^{n+a-2}} \\
& =\frac{(R+b)^2}{(n+a)(n+a-1)}
\end{align}
Then $\hat{t}=\frac{(n+a)(n+a-1)}{(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\log(X_i)+b)^2}$.

> I am asked to find the asymptotic distribution as well.

We have $\frac{(n+a)(n+a-1)}{(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\log(X_i)+b)^2}\stackrel{p}\to\alpha^2$ so it is a consistent estimator. I am trying to use the Central Limit Theorem, but need to find the variance, is my work up to now correct? If so, how do I find the asymptotic distribution?

Comment: Is $X_{(1)} = \max\big\{ X_k: k \in \{ 1 \ldots, n \} \big\}$? I think that $X_{(1)}$ usually denotes the minimum but in your case it should be maximum, because if $X_j \le 1$ for one $j \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$, then $\prod_{k = 1}^{n} 1(X_k > 1) = 0$. Also note that $f$ is the density of a Pareto$(1, \alpha)$ distribution.

Comment: I think a mistake you made is that the parameters, $\alpha = a + n$ and $\beta = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \log(X_k) + b$ you choose for the $\Gamma$ distribution depend on the sample $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, which shouldn't be the case - the parameters should be independent of the input sample.

Comment: Is $\alpha > 0$ and $X_k > 0$ almost surely for all $k \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$?

Comment: Can you please show how from a Gamma$(a, b)$ prior you calculated this posterior?

Comment: @Ramanujan The prior uses the hyperparameters a and b. I have added some notes on how I found the posterior. I have corrected the mistake you found on my derivative. As for the integral question since $f(\alpha|X)$ is a proper pdf it should integrate to one. As for the expectation question since $\alpha$ is the new random variable when $\int g(\alpha)f(\alpha|X)=E_{\alpha|X}g(\alpha)$. My mistake is that I just forgot to include the 2.

Comment: What about the issue with max instead of min I raised in my first comment? Also, are you sure the integrals with respect to $\alpha$ should be indefinite integrals instead of definite ones over $(0, \infty)$?

Comment: (I update my answer a bit.) Also, is the $P(X | \alpha)$ in the calculation of the posterior the expression you called $f(\underline{X} | \alpha)$ before?

Comment: @Ramanujan  $P(X|\alpha)$ is the expression I am using for the measure while $f(X|\alpha)$ is the pdf. As  for the integration it should be definite but I am using the indefinite notation for convenience. The min and max are used for identifying the support so if the min is above the threshold the remaining observations will also. As for the dependency on the data, I don't see a way where the posterior being dependent on X by definition will not have its parameters be a function of the data.

Answer (score 1):

For the conceptual understanding of the task it is important to keep in mind that, given $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, we are trying to estimate $\alpha > 0$.

---

- A mistake you made is that the parameters, $\alpha = a + n$ and $\beta = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \log(X_k) + b$, you gave for the posterior distribution depend on the sample $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, which shouldn't be the case - the parameters should be independent of the input sample.
  For the computation of the posterior, see [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625405/showing-the-posterior-distribution-is-a-gamma).
- You also seem to be claiming that
  $$
  \int f(X, \alpha) \; \text{d}(\alpha)
  = 1,
  $$
  which is not true (if you integrated over $X$, it would be true, because $f$ is a density): consider $n = 1$.
  Then (with the convention $0 \cdot \infty = 0$) we have
  $$
  \int_{0}^{\infty} \alpha X^{- \alpha - 1} 1_{\{ X > 1 \}}(x) \; \text{d}(\alpha)
  = 1_{\{ X > 1 \}}(x) \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} \alpha X^{- \alpha - 1} \; \text{d}(\alpha)
  = \frac{1}{x \log^2(x)} 1_{\{ X > 1 \}}(x),
  $$
  in particular this always depends on $x$.
- Also you seem to be claiming that
  $$
  \int \frac{2}{\alpha^2} f(\alpha | \underline{X}) \; \text{d}\alpha
  = E\left[\frac{1}{\alpha^2} | \underline{X}\right]
  = \int \alpha^{-2}\frac{(R+b)^{n+a}}{\Gamma(n+a)}\alpha^{n+a-1}e^{-\alpha(R+b)}\; \text{d}\alpha
  $$
  and I don't see how the term on the left and the term on the right should be equal, in particular because the term on the right depends on $a$ and $b$, while the term on the left does not.
  Lastly, I think those integrals should be definite ones over $(0, \infty)$ and not indefinite ones.