# Pareto distribution alternate form of joint density question

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, density-function

I know from that Pareto's pdf is:  $$f({\bf y};\theta,x_m) = \theta x_m^{\theta}  y^{-(\theta+1)} \mathbf{I}_{x_m<y}$$

Now the joint density is $$f({\bf y_1,\bf y_2,\dots,\bf y_n};\theta,x_m) = \theta x_m^{\theta}  y_1^{-(\theta+1)}\theta x_m^{\theta}  y_2^{-(\theta+1)},\dots,\theta x_m^{\theta}  y_n^{-(\theta+1)}= \theta^n x_m^{\theta n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}  y_i^{-(\theta+1)}\mathbf{I}_{x_m< \min(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}$$

But in another post on Stack Math I found another form of the joint density which you can found it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625405/showing-the-posterior-distribution-is-a-gamma), and the original poster writes it as :

$$f_n({\bf x}; \theta) = a^n b^{-n} \prod^n_{i=1}\left( \frac{b}{x_i} \right) ^{1 + a} $$

or in my notation :
$$f_n({\bf y}; \theta) = \theta^n x_m^{-n} \prod^n_{i=1}\left( \frac{x_m}{y_i} \right) ^{1 + \theta} $$

while my joint density is different:

$$ f_n({\bf y}; \theta) = \theta^n x_m^{\theta n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}  y_i^{-(\theta+1)}\mathbf{I}_{x_m< \min(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)}$$

What modifications has she/he  made in order to write it in that way ?

Can someone explain me specifically step by step how she/he has done it ? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(y;\theta,X_m)=\theta X_m^{\theta} \frac{1}{y^{\theta+1}}$$
\begin{align*}
    f(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n;\theta,X_m) &= \theta X_m^{\theta} \frac{1}{y_1^{\theta+1}}\theta X_m^{\theta} \frac{1}{y_2^{\theta+1}},\dots,\theta X_m^{\theta} \frac{1}{y_n^{\theta+1}}  \\
    &= \theta^{n} X_m^{\theta n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{y_i^{\theta+1}}\\
     &= \frac{\theta^{n} X_m^{\theta n}}{X_m} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_m}{y_i^{\theta+1}}\\
     &= \theta^{n} \left(\frac{1}{X_m}\right)^{n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_m X_m^{\theta }}{y_i^{\theta+1}}\\
      &= \theta^{n} X_m^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_m^{\theta +1}}{y_i^{\theta+1}}\\
        &= \theta^{n} X_m^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{X_m}{y_i}\right)^{\theta+1}
\end{align*}